# Adding the z-coordinates to depict a 3D force-directed-graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph-visualization, force-directed-graph

I tried to implement a 3D force directed graph in d3.js by the help of the following codes. But was unable to create the 3D network by adding the z-coordinates.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
 .node {
  fill: blue;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.node.visited {
  fill: red;
}

.link {
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

</style>

<body>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var width = 640;
var height = 480;

var links = [{
    source: 'Rohit',
    target: 'Deep'
  },
  {
    source: 'Deep',
    target: 'Deepa'
  },
  {
    source: 'Deepa',
    target: 'Rohit'
  },
];

var nodes = [{
    "id": 1,
    "desc": "Rohit",
    "x": 121.0284957885742,
    "y": 116.3165512084961,
    "z": 59.36788940429688
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "desc": "Deep",
    "x": 12.10284957885742,
    "y": 116.3165512084961,
    "z": 5.936788940429688
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "desc": "Deepa",
    "x": 12.10284957885742,
    "y": 11.63165512084961,
    "z": 5.936788940429688
  }
];

//adding to nodes
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] ||
    (nodes[link.source] = {
      name: link.source
    });

  link.target = nodes[link.target] ||
    (nodes[link.target] = {
      name: link.target
    });
});

//adding svg to body

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);

var defs = svg.append('defs');

var gradient = defs
  .append('linearGradient')
  .attr('id', 'svgGradient')
  .attr('x1', '0%')
  .attr('x2', '10%')
  .attr('y1', '0%')
  .attr('y2', '10%');

gradient
  .append('stop')
  .attr('class', 'start')
  .attr('offset', '0%')
  .attr('start-color', 'red')
  .attr('start-opacity', 1);

gradient
  .append('stop')
  .attr('class', 'end')
  .attr('offset', '100%')
  .attr('stop-color', 'blue')
  .attr('stop-opacity', 1);

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .size([width, height])
  .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
  .links(links)
  .on("tick", tick)
  .linkDistance(300)
  .start();

var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
  .data(links)
  .enter().append('line')
  .attr('class', 'link')
  .attr('stroke', 'url(#svgGradient)');

var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
  .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append('circle')
  .attr('class', 'node')
  .on("click", clicked)
  .attr('r', width * 0.03)
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr('cz', function(d){
    return d.z;
  });

//Code for clicking func.

function clicked(event, d) {
  if (event.defaultPrevented) return; // dragged

  d3.select(this).transition()
    .style("fill", "black")
    .attr("r", width * 0.2)
    .transition()
    .attr("r", width * 0.03)
    .transition()
    .style("fill", "blue")
  //.attr("fill", d3.schemeCategory10[d.index % 10]);
}


//define the tick func.
function tick(e) {
  node
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .attr('cz', function(d) {
      return d.z;
    })
    .call(force.drag);

  link
    .attr('x1', function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr('y1', function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr('z1', function(d) {
      return d.source.z;
    })
    .attr('x2', function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr('y2', function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    })
    .attr('z2', function(d) {
      return d.source.z;
    })

}

</script>


</body>
```

The image that came was carrying two parts one graph where the nodes are taking (x-y) coordinates assigned to them. And then I had another graph where the nodes are taking all x-y-z coordinates.

Can anyone please help us by telling how can we add the z co-ordinates to code.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example of the code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example